# When does STI make sense? We are storing the same information for every type but using it differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, single-table-inheritance, resque, sti

So I know STI is the most reviled thing ever but I have an instance where I think it might actually make sense.  My app is parsing a bunch of different types of xml files.  Every file model stores the exact same information.  Just some info about what user it is associated with, when it was uploaded, and where it is stored on S3.

After the xml file gets stored then I parse it for information which I use to create various other models.  Each type of file is going to create different things.  It is possible there could be 100 or more different types of xml files although I don't think I'm going to write parsers for that many.  Does STI make sense in this case?

The downside I guess is models are all in one directory so it is going to flood that directory unless hack Rails and stick it in a subdir in models dir.

The other option is I have a kind field and put something in the lib directory that handles all this.  Or I'm using resque, maybe every xml file parser should be it's own job. There are drawbacks to that though like it being kind of awkward to force a job in the rails console.

Comment: STI makes most sense, when there is same data, but different behaviour attached with data. For example, the person, can be a student and teacher. They both have similar attributes, but behave differently. Writing models for 100 types, doesn't make much sense to me. May be you should re-think a little bit.

Comment: You should probably make this an answer, i'd surely up-vote it.

Comment: 100 different models is an extreme but the xml files are representing finical forms and they contain vastly different data.  I need a way have each different type of form be able to do different things and have it organized well.  So i'm open to suggestions if it isn't STI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your explanation, the 'file' model is only storing the results of the file upload process and associated meta data. Without more information about the other kinds of models being generated from the parsed XML data, I don't see why single table inheritance applies to this use case.

Comment: Does it matter what type of models are generated? How would you handle this?